# How to migrate from directory of xml files on same server

Tags: migrations

I am completely new to using Migration. I need to migrate data from files that are contained in folders inside a directory that has already been transferred to the destination site. How do I set up the source information in the migration yml file.

For example if the source was at another url I might use something like:

source:
   plugin: url
   data_fetcher_plugin: http
   data_parser_plugin: xml
   urls: private://migration.xml

However so far I have not been able to find an example of how I would manage this for a directory of folders that contain xml files located inside the /sites/default/files directory.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Use the `public://` scheme, e.g. `public://migration.xml`

Comment: Thanks Hudri. So if the file is located at /sites/default/files/feeds/file.xml would I simply use public://file.xml?